# How to create table name with php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a table depending of the ID of each user, its stored in $id. So each user has its own calendar.

> For user #23 calendar created will be table "calendar23",

So Im using :

```
$id = 23;

CREATE TABLE calendar$id (.......
```

but its not working, what Im doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Gucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might missing any small thing. Try this.

```
$id = "table23";
// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE Persons".$id."(FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Table persons created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think again if that strategy really is the right approach. It ignores the benefits of relation database management systems. Instead use a single table for all users and mark entries with a user id each. This way your sql statements get much easier and secure.

If you really want to stick with your approach, then you'd have to prepare the statement:

```
$sql_stmt = sprintf('CREATE TABLE calendar%s (.......)', $id);
```

But this still is very insecure, as it is wide open to sql injection attacks. Read about prepared statements and use the mysqli or the PDO extension.